# pandas does not accept string concatenation as a name of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So i built some dataframe using pandas, and eventually i have to export a .csv file with it.

The code looks like this:

```
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

and it completely works. However, i need to place the day's date in front of the file_name for easy access and bookkeeping (this process is gonna be repeated many times). So i wrote something like this

```
today = '30/06/2021'
df.to_csv( today + 'file_name.csv')
```

but then it doesn't work, it raises: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '30/06/2021 file_name.csv'". I also tried many alternatives such as declaring

```
file_name = '30/06/2021 file_name.csv'
df.to_csv(file_name)
```

fstrings, string.format() but none worked.

**How can I use a variable string to complement file names in pandas?**

The full error reads:

```
  File "/home/vni/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3403, in to_csv
    storage_options=storage_options,
  File "/home/vni/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1083, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()
  File "/home/vni/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 234, in save
    storage_options=self.storage_options,
  File "/home/vni/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 652, in get_handle
    newline="",
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '28/06/2021 entregas_saida.csv'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hey. Vnii - pandas cannot find the file - probably the path is incorrect.

Comment: As the error message suggest, you should check if this file actually exists. Or if the path to the file is correct

Comment: You have `/` in your filename and that's going to be interpreted as a directory/filepath. Consider using dashes instead so it can write to your file system. If this is a windows systems then you can't use the following characters in your filename: `\/:*?"<>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: the file does not exist, i want to create it.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is trying to use `/` in the file name, using `-` works fine:

```
today = '30-06-2021'
df.to_csv( today + 'file_name.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like 'subfolders', .i.e  /30/06/.